# Program crash on boost::thread_group

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm facing an issue with boost::thread_group.
My software executes some image processing on images acquired from multiple cameras and so far, the single-thread/serial execution of operations are completed successfully and I've tested all the single functions using google-test framework, just to avoid the possibilities of some code-mistakes or crashes of algorithms.

When i enable the multithread processing, where i feed my processing function with different data (the data are not shared between the threads, but i want to process 4 images in parallel, to speed up the execution), i receive after a while an error of segmentation fault and the program quits. All the try/catch blocks are not avoiding this crash.

Is there any hint/way to process in parallel different data and store them on disk?

I'll write down the snippet of code which causes the error:

```
boost::thread_group processingThreads;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < images.size(); ++i)
{
     processingThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(processingFunction, i, param, backgrounds[i][0], images[i][0])); 
}
processingThreads.join_all();
```

where images and backgrounds are a std::vector> (one vector for each camera).
How can I deal with parallel executions of the same function? 
Is Boost suitable for this goal?

**EDIT**

processingFunction is structured as following (shortly, because it's a long function)

```
bool processingThread(const unsigned int threadID, const ProjectConfiguration &param, Images &background, Images &cloud)
{
    try{
           if(!loadImage(cloud))
           return false;

           ///Then: resize image, compute background mask, segment it.
           return true;
    catch(...){  return false; }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Mike

Comment: Show us the code in `processingFunction`.

Comment: @Nick processingFunction is a heavy and long function, which calls subroutines which deal with images operations.

Comment: My guess is that there is some shared state in your processing function and that would be the first place to look. If you're using 3rd party library code - is it thread safe? Spawning the threads looks ok to me.

Comment: I don't have shared states: the processingThreadFunction works with indipendent data, not shared between them and I create my own functional classes inside Processing Threads for doing some work on data.
The 3rd party libraries are thread safe (i guess OpenCV is thread-safe).

Comment: To be sure that OpenCV is thread-safe (at least in your usage), try removing all calls to OpenCV functions. Does it still segfaults?

Comment: I think it's a memory allocation/deallocation problem or an operating system's memory management problem.
I switched to unique_ptr where possible and the program runs fine for more then 1200 frames (images acquired and processed). Then, suddenly a segmentation fault comes, but with valgrind and gdb It's pretty hard to track this.
I need those opencv functions to be run in parallel unfortunately...
Should i think to move all to the C++11's async() ? 
The data are not related to each other and they can be processed in separated threads without any race condition on read or on write